# How many balls of radius 1 can be packed into a sphere of radius 10?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, packing-problem

How I can calculate the maximum number of balls of radius 1 that can be packed into a sphere of radius 10?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently, it is still an open question for spheres of radius $n$ for $n>5$.

See [A084828](http://oeis.org/A084828) in OEIS.